# Tell VS Code to resolve JSON Schema path from a directory

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

Is it possible to change the path from which VS Code resolves relative paths to schema files when they are referenced using `$ref` in another schema?

Assume I have two schemas:

- `/schemas/foo/schema-1.json`
- `/schemas/bar/schema-2.json`

If I want to reference `schema-1.json` from `schema-2.json`, I would need a property like this `"$ref": "../foo/schema-1.json"`. Is it possible to tell VS Code to resolve from a different path? I want to resolve from the path `/schemas` so I can use the following reference: `"$ref": "foo/schema-1.json"`.

The best solution would be, if I could make VS Code resolve all `$ref`s in a particular directory from a certail path, i.e. I would like to resolve all `$ref`s in the schema files `/schema/**/*.json` relative to `/schema`.

Comment: Can you explain why you believe "VS Code resolves relative paths to schema files when they are referenced using $ref in another schema" please?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Why do I belive that VS Code resolves relative paths to schemas?

Comment: Nearly but not quite. Specifically, why you believe VS Code corrolates `$ref` with the folder structure in your project?

Comment: Well... it just does. Whenever I write a relative path as the value of `$ref`, then VS Code is able to find it. And if I write a path to a file that does not exist it gives me an error.

Comment: Interesting. Is it documented? - Code gives you an error? Where and when and what is it?

Comment: Interestingly, I did not find any documentation. The error I get is simply code telling me, that it can not resolve the path to the file. I reckon you could simply try yourself by putting two simple JSON schema files into a single directory and then have one file `$ref` the other (like so: `"$ref": "./the-other.schema.json"`)

Comment: When you say "code", do you mean your code or VSCode? I'm unable to replicate. Can you update your question with a screenshot that includes the "problems" tab please? I'm wondering if you're gettint the error from an extension.